# How to install Web Platform Tools in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Which URL do I install this and any pre-reqs from, and how can I install them? Been struggling with this for the last 1 hour with no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

new 2013 answer:  it seems to depend on what version of eclipse you're running.

1. click "help" -> "about eclipse sdk" to find the version (e.g. 4.2.2).
2. optionally, from the version number you can know the codename (e.g. Juno) from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases
3. go here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F
4. right click on the correct WTP link copy the link address (e.g. WTP 3.4) (they should be listed by version and codename)
5. now in eclipse, click "help" -> "install new software..." and paste the link location in the "work with" field (e.g. "http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/").
6. choose "Web Tools Platform (WTP #.#.#)" and click next and install everything.
7. restart eclipse, close all open files and re-open them for web tools to start working.

Comment: great answer...!!

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a clean install of Eclipse. [Download Enterprise Java version](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/index.php?category=enterprise). WTP its included in this Eclipse distribution. When you need updates for WTP, you can get updates via "Eclipse Software Updates" tool.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can download WTP from Eclipse Help Menu. Following is the link to download the WTP into Eclipse.

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

[Install Software Menu in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ZpS.png)

Following image show the Install New Software Window.

[Install New Software window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DCKR.png)

Comment: Also Check http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna     In that you will find Web, XML, JAVA EE and OSGi Enterprise Development

Answer (score 0):

I try my best to stick to [Pulse](http://www.poweredbypulse.com), which handles a lot of the configuration of Eclipse plugins for you. I'm not associated with them by the way, but am very happy with the service. WTP is one of the features they provide.

Comment: I always wanted to like Pulse but why on Earth does it take 100% CPU when downloading addons? And regardless of it's sophisticated-looking download process, it's slower than regular eclipse.org downloads.