# XML editor with intellisense/autocomplete based on XML Schema

Tags: xml, linux, autocomplete, xsd, xml-editor

I'm looking for an XML editor that can provide auto completion and validation based on an XML schema. The target platform is Linux, with Win/OSX support desirable but optional.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958414/using-xml-schema-for-code-autocomplete-in-my-xml-editor) I'm aware that this is supported in Visual Studio. There are also several commercial XML Editors (oXygen, Liquid XML studio) that support this feature. I personally don't mind paid apps, but for this instance I'm looking to recommend the editor to a group of users, and requesting that they pay for an app will not go down well.

Any suggestions?

p.s. I had a quick stab at using Komodo Edit but could not get it to autocomplete based on a custom schema. Any tips on getting this working would help too.

#### (solved) comments:

Using *Eclipse* with the *Eclipse XML Editors and Tools* plugin works like a charm.  This solution has the added bonus of working on all target platforms. Thanks [@xcut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100450).

[This answer on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/98021/how-to-associate-xml-file-with-xsd-file-in-eclipse-for-autocomplete/98315#98315) states that *Eclipse* can do so without plugins but I could not replicate the claim.

As for my attempts at using *Komodo Edit*, it is apparently possible to do so if one [creates and registers an XML catalog](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/catalogs.html). However I could not get it working with XML schemas and all official documents from ActiveState specifically mentions DTD and RelaxNG only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try eclipse with eclipse Web Tools installed. As far as I know, that editor has auto-complete.

Of course, a full eclipse install might be overkill...

Comment: Thanks! I didnt have to install the complete WTP plataform, just "Eclipse Web Developer Tools" (the single inner one on the tree that has this on the description "... HTML, CSS, XHTML, etc.") and following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069163/1422630) plugin installation tip it was really fast to install! after restarting eclipse, the internal XML editor promptly begin working with the same configurations I had tried before and that didnt work (while without WTP).

Answer (score 0):

"[XAmple XML Editor](http://www.felixgolubov.com/XMLEditor/) project introduces a java Swing based XML editor that analyzes a given schema and then generates a document-specific graphical user interface. Unlike other XML editors, the XAmple XML editor GUI exposes not just a tree representation of the XML document but rather a logical combination of the XML document and respective XML Schema. The user interface of the XML editor is highly logical and intuitively comprehensible. To be able to prepare valid XML documents of significant complexity, a user is not required to be familiar with XML and XML Schema languages and to have any a-priori knowledge about the documents structural requirements."

I've tried it, and even my non-technical boss likes it.

Comment: The XAmple XML Editor URL is not reachable anymore

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea Community Edition comes with a good XML editor (enabled by default). It supports auto-complete based on the provided schema. Unfortunately it is an IDE as well as Eclipse, so it will be hard to make business users to use it.

Also you can use Ctrl-Q to view xs:documentation embedded into XML Schema.